# If $U\subseteq V$ is an $f$-invariant sub space is it also $f^{-1}$-invariant?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, invariant-theory

Assuming $V$ is finite dimensional and for some invertible  $f\in End(V)$ we have a subspace $U$ which is  $f$-invariant. Is $U$  also $f^{-1}$-invariant? 
My reasoning goes as follows:

Obviously $U\subseteq f^{-1}(U)$. If $dim(U)<dim( f^{-1}(U))$ then $\exists w\in  f^{-1}(U)\ w\neq0\ \  S.T\ ( f^{-1}(w))=0$. But $ f^{-1}$ is invertible and therefore injective.

But I have not seen this result anywhere else, is this proof valid or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is invertible and $U$ is finite dimensional, then $f(U) \subset U$ implies $f(U)=U$ since both sides have the same dimension. Applying $f^{-1}$ yields $f^{-1}(U)=U$. Hence the answer is affirmative.